# Acceder a DataTable creado dentro de función 'fetch' en JS

Tags: javascript, datatables, select, fetch

utilizo una llamada a la función fetch de javascript dentro de un select y, según el número de resultados de la llamada, me crea un datatable con éstos. Cuando no se reciben datos no se crea dicho dataTable. El problema lo tengo cuando quiero gestionar los clicks en las posibles filas de datos porqué me salta el error de que el dataTable no existe. Creando la variable con el dataTable fuera de el select me aparece el error de reinicilazión del dataTable.

```
$('#mybusqueda_fecha').change(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        let asesor = $("#listado #asesorMail").val();
        let tienda = $("#mybusqueda_tienda").val();
        let fecha = $("#mybusqueda_fecha").val();
        //Busca posibles informes para la tienda, fecha y asesor escogidos
        fetch("consultar.php?ac=listarInformes&rr=buit&ff=buit&as=" + asesor + "&fecha=" + fecha + "&tienda=" + tienda)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                let numInformes = data.length;
                if( numInformes != 0 ){
                    $('#mybusqueda_text_error').html('<font color="blue"><b>Existen informes para esta tienda y fecha, seleccione uno para editarlo o cree uno de nuevo</b></font>');
                    $('#btnBusqueda').html('Crear nuevo');
                    var $tabla_modal_informes = $('#resultados').dataTable({/*ESTO NO DEBE FUNCIONAR */
                        "language":{"url":"../../js/resources/dataTables.spanish.json"},
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        destroy: true,
                        data: data,
                        buttons:[],
                        paging:false,
                        searching: false,
                        info:false,
                        columns: [
                            { data:'referencia', visible:false},
                            { data:'nombre_asesor', title:'ASESOR'},
                            { data:'hora_entrada', title:'HORA ENTRADA'},
                            { data:'hora_salida', title:'HORA SALIDA'},
                            { data:'nota', title:'NOTA'},
                        ],
                        columnDefs: [
                            {
                                targets: -1,
                                className: 'dt-center',
                            }
                        ],
                    });
                    $('#resultados').show();
                }else{
                    $('#resultados').hide();
                    $('#mybusqueda_text_error').html('<font color="blue"><b>No existe informes para esta tienda y fecha, puede crear uno de nuevo</b></font>');
                    $('#btnBusqueda').html('Crear nuevo');

                }
        });
    });
    //cuando hacemos click en sus filas
    $('#resultados').on('click','tr',function () {
        $('#resultados').rows().deselect();
        // Ontiene datos de la fila seleccionada
        let informe = $('#resultados').row(this).data();
    })
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor haría falta el html de los elementos que estás invocando en tu javascript así como un [example] de los datos recibidos con ajax.  Puedes [edit] la pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace Editar que aparece en el pie de la pregunta

Comment: Aparte de eso, ¿si cambias `$tabla_modal_informes` por `$('#resultados')` no te funciona?

Comment: Buenas, gracias por el aporte. No, no funciona. Los datos se cargan bien, no sé cómo hacer lo que me pide. El problema es que al crear la tabla "dentro" del fetch anidado en el 'select' cuando quiero gestionar los clicks me dice que la tabla no existe. En el caso de hacer tu sustitución, el error que me aparece es que la función row() no existe, cómo si no tuviera cargado el dataTable

Comment: ¿y si pones ese bloque de código dentro despues del show?

Comment: Perdona mi torpeza, pero no entiendo, ¿después del "show"? ¿Dónde  está ese show?

Comment: $('#resultados').show();

Comment: Lo que querría hacer y no sé cómo hacerlo, sería poder declarar el dataTable sin propiedades, fuera del select con una variable y relleneralo si es necesario dentro del fetch. De esa manera, las funciones del dataTable estarían disponibles desde cualquier parte del código JS. Pero no sé cómo hacerlo

Comment: Probé tu opción y tampoco me funcionó

Comment: vamos paso a paso... primero ponlo despues del show() y a ver que sucede, y luego ya lo declararemos fuera si es necesario... y cambia también esto `$('#resultados').dataTable(` por esto: `$('#resultados').DataTable(` (con la D en mayúscula)

Comment: Funcionó! Los dos pasos que usted me indicó eran los necesarios para que todo funcionara. El DataTables inicializado con la D en mayúscula y el código de la función on() dentro del mismo bloque dónde se declara e inicializa el DataTables.

Comment: Bien! :-)  Me alegro que lo hayas solucionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo los pasos de masterguru, debía inicializar el DataTables con la 'D' en mayúsculas y, además, debía mover el código de gestión de los clicks, función on(), dentro del bloque dónde declaraba la variable DataTable.

El código rectificado:

```
$('#mybusqueda_fecha').change(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        let asesor = $("#listado #asesorMail").val();
        let tienda = $("#mybusqueda_tienda").val();
        let fecha = $("#mybusqueda_fecha").val();
        //Busca posibles informes para la tienda, fecha y asesor escogidos
        fetch("consultar.php?ac=listarInformes&rr=buit&ff=buit&as=" + asesor + "&fecha=" + fecha + "&tienda=" + tienda)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                let numInformes = data.length;
                if( numInformes != 0 ){
                    $('#mybusqueda_text_error').html('<font color="blue"><b>Existen informes para esta tienda y fecha, seleccione uno para editarlo o cree uno de nuevo</b></font>');
                    $('#btnBusqueda').html('Crear nuevo');
                    var $tabla_modal_informes = $('#resultados').DataTable({/*ESTO NO DEBE FUNCIONAR */
                        "language":{"url":"../../js/resources/dataTables.spanish.json"},
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        destroy: true,
                        data: data,
                        buttons:[],
                        paging:false,
                        searching: false,
                        info:false,
                        columns: [
                            { data:'referencia', visible:false},
                            { data:'nombre_asesor', title:'ASESOR'},
                            { data:'hora_entrada', title:'HORA ENTRADA'},
                            { data:'hora_salida', title:'HORA SALIDA'},
                            { data:'nota', title:'NOTA'},
                        ],
                        columnDefs: [
                            {
                                targets: -1,
                                className: 'dt-center',
                            }
                        ],
                    });
                    $('#resultados').show();
                    //cuando hacemos click en sus filas
                    $('#resultados').on('click','tr',function () {
                        $tabla_modal_informes.rows().deselect();
                        // Ontiene datos de la fila seleccionada
                        let informe = $tabla_modal_informes.row(this).data();
                        console.log(informe);
                    });
                }else{
                    $('#resultados').hide();
                    $('#mybusqueda_text_error').html('<font color="blue"><b>No existe informes para esta tienda y fecha, puede crear uno de nuevo</b></font>');
                    $('#btnBusqueda').html('Crear nuevo');

                }
        });
    });
```